# Service worker uses incorrect (cached) Content Security Policy

Tags: apache, http, caching, service-worker, content-security-policy

I've discovered an interesting issue when attempting to use Content Security Policy to secure my site and also ServiceWorker to speed it up and let it run offline.

It's a standard Wordpress site and Plugin developers have a naughty habit of using external resources, particularly in the /wp-admin/ section. I don't what to whitelist a ton of stuff on the main site (particularly unsafe-eval, a frequent culprit in the admin section), so what I did was make a main CSP, then in /wp-admin/ I unset and reset a less restrictive set.

Here's a sample of the code I'm using to unset the CSP when you're in the admin area of the site:

```
<Location /wp-admin/>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always unset  Content-Security-Policy
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header set Content-Security-Policy " default-src 'self' ps.w.org;" 
</IfModule>

</Location>
```

And it works fine unless you've been to (or have another tab open to) the main area of the site, at which point the ps.w.org directive (and others) are ignored. A bunch of assets end up blocked, scripts don't work, etc. Refreshing the page while in the admin section temporarily loads the correct CSP, so I know it's being used; it's just being overwritten by the main one. Sometimes the same happens to the main site, loading the admin CSP too.

Is the ServiceWorker caching the CSP or what exactly is going on here? Is there some way to get the ServiceWorker to respect the CSP that page should be sending in it's headers? For now I've just merged the two CSP settings into one and removed my over-broad rules for the admin area but it's not ideal.

Comment: Does this info help? https://qubyte.codes/blog/content-security-policy-and-service-workers

Comment: I think that https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/755 is related to your issue, no?